# Subtracting indexes - TypeError: cannot perform __sub__ with this index type: <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>

Tags: python, pandas

I have two huge dataframes
I'm merging them, but I don't want to have repeated columns, so I'm selecting columns by subtracting them:

```
cols_to_use=df_fin.columns-df_peers.columns.difference(['cnpj'])
df=df_peers.merge(df_fin[cols_to_use],on='cnpj',how='left')
```

I'm getting this error (in the first line):

```
TypeError: cannot perform __sub__ with this index type: <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>

df_fin.columns:
Index(['cnpj', 'ano', 'id', 'unit', 'period', 'Ativo Circulante',
   'Ativo Nao-Circulante', 'Ativo Total', 'Custos', 'Depreciacao',
   'Despesas Financeiras', 'EBITDA', 'Lucro Antes do Resultado Financeiro',
   'Lucro Antes dos Impostos', 'Lucro Bruto', 'Lucro Liquido',
   'Passivo Circulante', 'Passivo Nao-Circulante', 'Passivo Total',
   'Patrimonio Liquido', 'Receita Liquida', 'Receitas Financeiras',
   'Crescimento', 'MgLucro', 'Custo/Receita', 'MgBruta', 'MgEBITDA',
   'Passivo/EBITDA', 'LiqCorrente', 'LiqGeral', 'Resultado Financeiro',
   'RFinanceiro/Receita', 'ROA', 'ROE', 'Razao_social', 'Nome_Fantasia',
   'Estado', 'Cidade', 'CNAE', '#CNAE', 'Capital_Social', 'Data_fundacao',
   'CEP', 'Bairro', 'Rua', 'Numero', 'Complemento_endereco',
   'Natureza_Juridica', 'Telefone', 'email', 'last_revenue_normalized',
   'last_revenue_year', 'situacao_cadastral', 'situacao_especial',
   'Unnamed: 0'],
  dtype='object')

df_peers.columns:
Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'cnpj', 'Razao_social', 'Nome_Fantasia', 'Estado',
   'Cidade', 'CNAE', '#CNAE', 'Capital_Social', 'Data_fundacao',
   ...
   'Custo/Receita_t44_Peers_CNAEbisavo_estado_porte',
   'MgBruta_t44_Peers_CNAEbisavo_estado_porte',
   'Crescimento_t44_Peers_CNAEbisavo_estado_porte',
   'cnpj_t44_Peers_CNAEbisavo_estado_porte',
   'MgEBITDA_t44_Peers_CNAEbisavo_estado_porte',
   'Passivo/EBITDA_t44_Peers_CNAEbisavo_estado_porte',
   'ROE_t44_Peers_CNAEbisavo_estado_porte',
   'RFinanceiro/Receita_t44_Peers_CNAEbisavo_estado_porte',
   'ROA_t44_Peers_CNAEbisavo_estado_porte',
   'MgLucro_t44_Peers_CNAEbisavo_estado_porte'],
  dtype='object', length=250)
```

Does someone know what that could mean or an alternative way of doing the same thing?

Comment: I believe you want the union, not the difference.`df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b']) ; df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['b', 'c']) ; print(set(df1.columns).union(df2.columns))` which outputs `{'a', 'b', 'c'}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the difference in indexes there is [`difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) (which you're already using). You cannot subtract `columns` via `-` - the error is telling you that the lass does not support this operation.

To find all columns in `df_fin` that are not in `df_peers`, you can use

```
cols_to_use=df_fin.columns.difference(df_peers.columns)
```

If you would like to remove from this `cnpj` as well, you could use

```
cols_to_use=df_fin.columns.difference(df_peers.columns).difference(['cnpj'])
```

---

**Edit**

If you want to get the union of columns (in order) without duplicates, you can use

```
from collections import OrderedDict

list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(list(df_fin.columns) + list(df_peers.columns)))
```

Comment: Using this code I get only the columns in df_fin that are not present in df_peers, when actually I want all columns present in both but I don't want repeated columns with suffixes